# Is there a way, on macos, to associate vscode close window to a shortcut?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

If I search for a "close window" feature in the command palette, I get this:

[image: Close main Window]

which is the main command one activates by clicking the os tick to close the whole window of vscode.
Activating this from the command palette is useful to close the main window if in full screen.
**Is there a way to associate this command to a shortcut?**

*When I search for "close window" in the shortcut view I find:*

[image]

*where "shift+cmd+w" closes all internal windows of vscode and "cmd+w" closes them one by one (finally "cmd+q" just shuts down vscode entirely)*

Answer (score 5):

Apparently now it is possible to close one instance only of vscode, with the standard shift+cmd+w, to recap

**on windows and linux**
Simply just use alt+f4 to close your vscode window

**on macos**
Use shift+cmd+w

..or any other key combination you might associate with `workbench.action.closeWindow`